# Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I know this has been asked several times but i cant seem to get a solution that works for me.I am Using my Students service and staff service to call my staff and student objects at my courses controller.I am trying to get the objects staffs and students objects to getso i can access their name properties to display.The course object just has an array that stores a staffIDs and StudentIDs.My staff services works just as its supposed to bt my student gets the above error.
I am tring to get a list of all students and staff registered to the course.
If there is a cleaner implementation of my code all suggestions are welcomed

The Course Controller

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  // Courses controller
 angular
.module('courses')
.controller('CoursesController', CoursesController);

CoursesController.$inject =   ['$scope','StaffsService','StudentsService','$state','$filter', 'Authentication', 'courseResolve'];

function CoursesController   ($scope,StaffsService,StudentsService,$state,$filter, Authentication, course) {
var vm = this;

vm.authentication = Authentication;
vm.course = course;
vm.error = null;
vm.form = {};
vm.remove = remove;
vm.save = save;
//Array of filtered staff
var temp = [];
$scope.liststaff = []; 
//List of all   
StaffsService.query(function(resource){
$scope.liststaff = resource;
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.liststaff.length; i++){
  if(vm.course.staff == undefined){
        vm.course.staff = [];
    }
if(vm.course.staff.indexOf($scope.liststaff[i]._id) > -1){
  $scope.liststaff[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
});

  $scope.coursesStaff = []; 
  $scope.coursesStudent = [];

//get staff courses object to get course title
if(vm.course.staff!=undefined){
 for ( var i = 0; i < vm.course.staff.length; i++) { 
     $scope.coursesStaff[i] = StaffsService.get({ staffId:    vm.course.staff[i] });     
  }
}

//Get list of students taking this course
 if(vm.course.student!=undefined){
  for ( var i = 0; i < vm.course.student.length; i++) { 
     var some = StudentsService.get({ student_Id: vm.course.student[i] });
     console.log(some);
      $scope.coursesStudent[i] = some;
  }
}


 //Filter for assigning staff to this course
 $scope.selectedStaff = function () {
    temp = $filter('filter')($scope.liststaff,({checked: true}));    
 }

// Remove existing Course
function remove() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {

    if($scope.coursesStudent != undefined){

      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.coursesStudent.length; i++){
      var index = $scope.coursesStudent[i].course.indexOf(vm.course._id);
      $scope.coursesStudent[i].course.splice(index,1);
      var temp = $scope.coursesStudent[i];
      var id = vm._id
      StudentsService.update({id:id},temp);
      }
    }

    if($scope.coursesStaff != undefined){

      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.coursesStaff.length; i++){
      var index = $scope.coursesStaff[i].courses.indexOf(vm.course._id);
      $scope.coursesStaff[i].courses.splice(index,1);
      var temp = $scope.coursesStaff[i];
      var id = vm._id
      StaffsService.update({id:id},temp);
      }
    }
    vm.course.$remove($state.go('courses.list'));
  }
}

// Save Course
function save(isValid) {
  if (!isValid) {
    $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'vm.form.courseForm');
    return false;
  }

  // TODO: move create/update logic to service
  if (vm.course._id) {
    vm.course.$update(successCallback, errorCallback);
  } else {
    vm.course.$save(successCallback, errorCallback);
  }

    for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.liststaff.length; i++) {  
    if($scope.liststaff[i].checked == true){    
      if(vm.course.staff == undefined){
        vm.course.staff = [];
      }
      if(vm.course.staff.indexOf($scope.liststaff[i]._id) == -1){

          vm.course.staff.push($scope.liststaff[i]._id); 
          var temp = $scope.liststaff[i];
          temp.courses.push(vm.course._id);
          var id = $scope.liststaff[i]._id;
          StaffsService.update({id:id},temp);
        }

      }
      //remove items tht were unchecked from parent object
      else{
        var index = vm.course.staff.indexOf($scope.liststaff[i]._id)
        if (index > -1) {
            vm.course.staff.splice(index, 1);
            var nuindex = $scope.liststaff[i].courses.indexOf(vm.course._id);
            $scope.liststaff[i].courses.splice(nuindex,1);
            var id = $scope.liststaff[i]._id;
            var temp = $scope.liststaff[i];
            StaffsService.update({id:id},temp);
        }

      } 
    }

  function successCallback(res) {
    $state.go('courses.view', {
      courseId: res._id
    });
  }

  function errorCallback(res) {
    vm.error = res.data.message;
      }
    }
     }
      })();
```

Student Service

```
 (function () {
      'use strict';

      angular
        .module('students')
        .factory('StudentsService', StudentsService);

      StudentsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

      function StudentsService($resource) {
        return $resource('api/students/:studentId', {
          studentId: '@_id'
        }, {
          update: {
            method: 'PUT'
          }
        });
      }
    })();
```

Staff Service

```
    (function () {
      'use strict';

      angular
        .module('staffs')
        .factory('StaffsService', StaffsService);

      StaffsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

      function StaffsService($resource) {
        return $resource('api/staffs/:staffId', {
          staffId: '@_id'
        }, {
          update: {
            method: 'PUT'
          }
        });
      }
    })();
```

HTML for output

```
    <section>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1 data-ng-bind="vm.course.title"></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right"
           data-ng-show="vm.course.isCurrentUserOwner">
        <a class="btn btn-primary"
           data-ui-sref="courses.edit({ courseId: vm.course._id })">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="vm.remove()">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
     <h3>Student</h3>
     <div class="list-group">
        <a data-ng-repeat="student in coursesStudent"
           data-ui-sref="students.view({ studentId: student._id })"
           class="list-group-item" >

          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{student.name}}</h4>
        </a>
      </div>
     <h3>Staff</h3>
     <div class="list-group">
        <a data-ng-repeat="staff in coursesStaff"
           data-ui-sref="staffs.view({ staffId: staff._id })"
           class="list-group-item">

          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-ng-bind="staff.firstname"></h4>
        </a>
      </div>

      <small>
        <em class="text-muted">
          Posted on
          <span data-ng-bind="vm.course.created | date:'mediumDate'"></span>
          by
          <span data-ng-if="vm.course.user"
                data-ng-bind="vm.course.user.displayName"></span>
          <span data-ng-if="!vm.course.user">Deleted User</span>
        </em>
      </small>
      <p class="lead" data-ng-bind="vm.course.content"></p>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you have:
        data-ng-bind="staff.firstname">
Could you change this to:
        {{ staff.firstname }} 
Apart from that I am struggling to see the error, knowing Angular when something goes wrong it is normally down to scope. +1 for good use of Angular Services.